# jQuery animate set fallback

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible to set a fallback inside a jQuery animate function like in css.
Because e.g. calc() isn't working in all browsers.

CSS:

```
.element {
width: 33.33%;
width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

Something like that:

```
$('.element').animate({
'width': 33.33%,
'width': calc(100% / 3)
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "fallback"?

Comment: @guest271314 well calc() is not working in all browsers

Comment: _"calc() is not working in all browsers"_ The pattern at Question should render expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be a better option to add class for the task you want

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('.element').addClass('animation');
      
   
  })
```

```css
.element{width:100px;height:100px;background:lightblue}
   .animation{
     animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation:move 2s 1 ease-in-out;
    }
    @keyframes move{
       0%{width:100%;}
       }
    100%{width:calc(100%/3);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element"></div>
```